# Java Decompiler how to use?

Tags: java, decompiler, jad

I have lost my sources but I have my executable .jar file. I want to apply [JAD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAD_%28JAva_Decompiler%29) to it. 
What options to use to start UI with all source tree of .jar file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend [Java Decompiler](http://java.decompiler.free.fr/)

Comment: @EmmanuelDupuy, Kudos to you for that great tool! Saved me a couple of projects with legacy classes already :D

Comment: Thanks Andreas_D. I am tired to see that people associate the decompilers with the hacking. JD is not tools for the pirates. I did it for me, developers, and security or performance experts.

Comment: "Erreur 403 - Refus de traitement de la requête (Interdit - Forbidden)"

Answer (score 1):

1. Download JAD Command..
2. paste it in your jdk/bin directory.
3. type in cmd   [ jdk/bin> jad -sjava example.claass ]

Link below answers u in detail:
http://www.papervisions.com/get-java-source-file-from-class-file-how-to/

Comment: JAD used to be great, but it is less useful over the years. I'm not sure what the go-to decompiler is anymore, but I don't think it's JAD! The last time I looked at it, it couldn't figure out my Java 7 code.

Answer (score 0):

JAD has online, in-the-cloud interface now: http://www.javadecompilers.com/

Comment: Technically, that site offers interfaces to a variety of Java decompilers, with the rather ancient and unmaintained JAD being on of them. To quote the site: "given here only for historical reason."

Comment: Actually, I hope that the topic-starter would choose another, modern decompiler. Why JAD? :0)

Answer (score -3):

I mostly use Javadecompilers.com to decode my Jar file. The site can also decode android applications (.APK) which, I think, is very good for those who are beginners in android application development since you can learn from source code !. This is not STEALING. It is just "Break the code to see how it was made so that you can learn from it" !